# How to recycle bitmap during game development?

Tags: android, android-intent

Am having three activities and each activty contains single view

1. main activity-> progressbar view
2. help activity
3. game activity -> game view (with multiple classes)

like that while am switching from game to main activity how can i recycle my bitmap?
how can i null my sprite images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Bitmap.recycle()` for every `Bitmap` in your `onPause()` method, and reinitialize them in `onResume()`. `Bitmap.recycle()` will free your objects from the memory, so you don't have to set them to null explicitly.